# Change image based on two spinners

Tags: java, android, image

I have spent about 3 days searching for this answer and I finally decided to create the question myself.

Basically I have an activity with two spinners on it. One is the type of hair and the other is the color of the hair. You see where I am going with this. I want to be able for the picture (on a head) to change depending on the two items selected.

Incase I'm not making sense here's an example:

1. Activity loaded (Spinners set to "Bald" and "Black)

   - Hair is bald.
2. Change hair type to 'Male Short'

   - Hair changes to short black male hair.
3. Change color to 'Blonde'

   - Hair changes to short blonde male hair.

But step 3 doesn't work!!!

This code is far too long but most of it is repeated stuff so shouldn't take too long to understand :)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.head_zoom);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Spinner hairSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hairSpinner);
    hairSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    List<String> hairTypeArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    hairTypeArray.add("Bald");
    hairTypeArray.add("Female Short");
    hairTypeArray.add("Female Medium");
    hairTypeArray.add("Female Long");
    hairTypeArray.add("Male Short");
    hairTypeArray.add("Male Medium");
    hairTypeArray.add("Male Long");
    ArrayAdapter<String> hairTypeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hairTypeArray);
    hairTypeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    hairSpinner.setAdapter(hairTypeAdapter);

    Spinner hairColor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hairColor);
    hairColor.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    List<String> hairColorArray = new ArrayList<>();
    hairColorArray.add("Black");
    hairColorArray.add("Blonde");
    hairColorArray.add("Blue");
    hairColorArray.add("Brown");
    hairColorArray.add("Ginger");
    hairColorArray.add("Green");
    hairColorArray.add("Red");
    ArrayAdapter<String> hairColorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hairColorArray);
    hairColorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    hairColor.setAdapter(hairColorAdapter);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    String type = "Bald", color = "Black";
    //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: "+item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
    if(spinner.getId() == R.id.hairSpinner) {
        type = item;
    }
    else {
        color = item;
    }

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.head);
    switch(type){
        case "Bald":
            imageView.setImageResource((R.drawable.sw_head));
            break;
        case "Female Short":
            if(color=="Black")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_black);
            else if(color=="Blonde")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_blonde);
            else if(color=="Blue")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_blue);
            else if(color=="Brown")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_brown);
            else if(color=="Ginger")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_ginger);
            else if(color=="Green")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_green);
            else if(color=="Red")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_red);
            break;
        case "Female Medium":
            if(color=="Black")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_black);
            else if(color=="Blonde")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_blonde);
            else if(color=="Blue")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_blue);
            else if(color=="Brown")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_brown);
            else if(color=="Ginger")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_ginger);
            else if(color=="Green")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_green);
            else if(color=="Red")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_red);
            break;
        case "Female Long":
            if(color=="Black")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_long_black);
            else if(color=="Blonde")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_long_blonde);
            else if(color=="Blue")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_long_blue);
            else if(color=="Brown")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_long_brown);
            else if(color=="Ginger")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_long_ginger);
            else if(color=="Green")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_long_green);
            else if(color=="Red")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_long_red);
            break;
        case "Male Short":
            if(color=="Black")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_short_black);
            else if(color=="Blonde")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_short_blonde);
            else if(color=="Blue")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_short_blue);
            else if(color=="Brown")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_short_brown);
            else if(color=="Ginger")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_short_ginger);
            else if(color=="Green")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_short_green);
            else if(color=="Red")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_short_red);
            break;
        case "Male Medium":
            if(color=="Black")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_med_black);
            else if(color=="Blonde")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_med_blonde);
            else if(color=="Blue")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_med_blue);
            else if(color=="Brown")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_med_brown);
            else if(color=="Ginger")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_med_ginger);
            else if(color=="Green")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_med_green);
            else if(color=="Red")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_med_red);
            break;
        case "Male Long":
            if(color=="Black")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_long_black);
            else if(color=="Blonde")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_long_blonde);
            else if(color=="Blue")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_long_blue);
            else if(color=="Brown")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_long_brown);
            else if(color=="Ginger")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_long_ginger);
            else if(color=="Green")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_long_green);
            else if(color=="Red")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_long_red);
            break;
    }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){

}
```

The problem is that whenever an item is selected from either spinner it activates the listener but doesn't take the other spinner into account. So if I change the hair color it resets to bald because of

```
    String type = "Bald", color = "Black";
```

I appreciate any help you can give, thank you.

Comment: In you exemple, why is the colour not changed to blonde ? It should be Male Short Blonde hair, no ?

Comment: Yeah I was explaining what happens at the moment. Sorry, that was unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The problem in the end was that I had initialized the lists twice, once in global and once in onCreate. I removed this from onCreate and changed `color=="black"` to `color.equals("black")`.

This is my code now:

```
public class HeadZoom extends MainActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

private Spinner hairSpinner;
private Spinner hairColor;
private String type;
private String color;
private ImageView imageView;
private List<String> hairTypeArray = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> hairColorArray = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.head_zoom);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.head);
    type="Bald";

    hairSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hairSpinner);
    hairSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    hairTypeArray.add("Bald");
    hairTypeArray.add("Female Short");
    hairTypeArray.add("Female Medium");
      (...)
    ArrayAdapter<String> hairTypeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hairTypeArray);
    hairTypeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    hairSpinner.setAdapter(hairTypeAdapter);

    color = "Black";

    hairColor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hairColor);
    hairColor.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    hairColorArray.add("Black");
    hairColorArray.add("Blonde");
    hairColorArray.add("Blue");
      (...)
    ArrayAdapter<String> hairColorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hairColorArray);
    hairColorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    hairColor.setAdapter(hairColorAdapter);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    if(parent.getId()==hairSpinner.getId())
        type = hairTypeArray.get(position);
    else
        color = hairColorArray.get(position);

    switch(type){
        case "Bald":
            imageView.setImageResource((R.drawable.sw_head));
            break;
        case "Female Short":
            if(color.equals("Black"))
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_black);
            else if(color.equals("Blonde"))
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_blonde);
            else if(color.equals("Blue"))
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_blue);
            else if(color.equals("Brown"))
                (...)
                break;
        case "Female Medium":
            if(color.equals("Black"))
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_black);
            else if(color.equals("Blonde"))
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_blonde);
            else if(color.equals("Blue"))
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_blue);
            else if(color.equals("Brown"))
                (...)
                break;
        case "Female Long":
               (...)
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){

}
```

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to split the switch in two different ones, one for hairtype and other for haircolor. What you are doing now is getting the the hairtype and a break, never coming to the color aspect.

```
        if (view == hairSpinner){
        switch (item){
            case "Bald":
            case "Female Short":
            case "Female Medium":
            case "Female Long":
            case "Male Short":
            case "Male Medium":
            case "Male Long":
                type = item;
                break;
        }
    }
    else{
        switch (item){
            case "Black":
            case "Blonde":
            case "Blue":
            case "Brown":
            case "Ginger":
            case "Green":
            case "Red":
                color = item;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: And of course you need to declare the spinner outside of the onCreate method to enable the test in onItemSelected.

Comment: I have added an edit so you can see what i have changed but it is still not working. The activity loads and crashes right away.

Comment: You have to declare hairSpinner and hairColor global to your class and not inside one of the methods. And then you can test if(view==hairSpiner) etc..

Comment: Don't use this Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent; , because you allready have a reference to the spinners which is view.

Comment: I moved `Spinner hairSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hairSpinner);` and `Spinner hairColor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hairColor);` above the onCreate method and now it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Geraldo's answer is the right answer in your case. But this is going to be very long as you have a lot of types and colours, and it won't be very customizable.
 If I were you I would try to create drawables for the type (only the shape, with no colour), and drawables for the colour. In this case you can easily apply colour to type, and type to colour, with just two simple variables that will identify the current type and the current colour.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. At the moment I have images with all the types in different colors.

Comment: I know, I'm saying it would be better if you had images for the types and images for the colours so you can customize the hair easier by overlapping both images

Comment: I see what you mean. I think I will save that until I decide to give up doing it this way

Comment: Haha sounds like something I would do too

Answer (score 1):

David you are right and besides he doesn't even need to use a switch, because the next will have the same effect;

```
        String type=null;
    String color=null;

    if (view==hairSpinner)
        type = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    else
        color = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

What I mean is something like this:

```
public class Test
extends AppCompatActivity
implements OnItemSelectedListener{


private Spinner hairSpinner;    
private Spinner hairColor;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
    hairSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hairSpinner);
    ...
    hairColor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hairColor);
    ...
}


public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    String type=null;
    String color=null;

    if (view==hairSpinner)
    type = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        else
    color = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
}
```

}

Comment: I see what you mean now. Though it still is not working. If color and type are set to null the app crashes but when I give them values the Toast works but the pictures are not appearing. Perhaps the switch statements aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

This time it should work.....

```
public class MainActivity
    extends AppCompatActivity
    implements OnItemSelectedListener{


private Spinner hairSpinner;
private Spinner hairColor;
private String type;
private String color;
private ImageView imageView;
private List<String> hairTypeArray = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> hairColorArray = new ArrayList<String>();


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.head_zoom);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.head);

    type="Bald";

    hairSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hairSpinner);
    hairSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    hairTypeArray.add("Bald");
    hairTypeArray.add("Female Short");
    hairTypeArray.add("Female Medium");
    hairTypeArray.add("Female Long");
    hairTypeArray.add("Male Short");
    hairTypeArray.add("Male Medium");
    hairTypeArray.add("Male Long");
    ArrayAdapter<String> hairTypeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hairTypeArray);
    hairTypeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    hairSpinner.setAdapter(hairTypeAdapter);

    color = "Black";

    hairColor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hairColor);
    hairColor.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    hairColorArray.add("Black");
    hairColorArray.add("Blonde");
    hairColorArray.add("Blue");
    hairColorArray.add("Brown");
    hairColorArray.add("Ginger");
    hairColorArray.add("Green");
    hairColorArray.add("Red");
    ArrayAdapter<String> hairColorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                                                     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hairColorArray);
    hairColorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    hairColor.setAdapter(hairColorAdapter);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

    if (parent.getId()==hairSpinner.getId())
        type = hairTypeArray.get(position);
    else
        color = hairColorArray.get(position);


    switch(type){
        case "Bald":
            imageView.setImageResource((R.drawable.sw_head));
            break;
        case "Female Short":
            if(color=="Black")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_black);
            else if(color=="Blonde")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_blonde);
            else if(color=="Blue")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_blue);
            else if(color=="Brown")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_brown);
            else if(color=="Ginger")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_ginger);
            else if(color=="Green")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_green);
            else if(color=="Red")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_red);
            break;
        case "Female Medium":
            if(color=="Black")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_black);
            else if(color=="Blonde")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_blonde);
            else if(color=="Blue")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_blue);
            else if(color=="Brown")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_brown);
            else if(color=="Ginger")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_ginger);
            else if(color=="Green")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_green);
            else if(color=="Red")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_red);
            break;
        case "Female Long":
            if(color=="Black")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_long_black);
            else if(color=="Blonde")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_long_blonde);
            else if(color=="Blue")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_long_blue);
            else if(color=="Brown")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_long_brown);
            else if(color=="Ginger")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_long_ginger);
            else if(color=="Green")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_long_green);
            else if(color=="Red")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_long_red);
            break;
        case "Male Short":
            if(color=="Black")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_short_black);
            else if(color=="Blonde")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_short_blonde);
            else if(color=="Blue")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_short_blue);
            else if(color=="Brown")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_short_brown);
            else if(color=="Ginger")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_short_ginger);
            else if(color=="Green")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_short_green);
            else if(color=="Red")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_short_red);
            break;
        case "Male Medium":
            if(color=="Black")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_med_black);
            else if(color=="Blonde")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_med_blonde);
            else if(color=="Blue")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_med_blue);
            else if(color=="Brown")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_med_brown);
            else if(color=="Ginger")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_med_ginger);
            else if(color=="Green")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_med_green);
            else if(color=="Red")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_med_red);
            break;
        case "Male Long":
            if(color=="Black")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_long_black);
            else if(color=="Blonde")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_long_blonde);
            else if(color=="Blue")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_long_blue);
            else if(color=="Brown")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_long_brown);
            else if(color=="Ginger")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_long_ginger);
            else if(color=="Green")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_long_green);
            else if(color=="Red")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mhair_long_red);
            break;
    }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){
}
```

}

Comment: This still crashes after the activity is open. Would you like me to post the error report?